# HTML button that triggers a page without navigating to that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, esp8266

Apologies in advance - I've found a few questions that appear to almost address this but don't quite pull it together.  I'm also not sure if I am even thinking about this correctly from a conceptual standpoint.

I'm trying to create an HTML button that "goes to" a link in the sense that the link is triggered but does not "go to" a link in the sense that the page at that link is loaded.

Background:

I'm working on using some ESP8266 boards to turn things on and off via a web interface.  The board hosts a simple server and responds to clicks on the page (modified from [source](https://www.teachmemicro.com/simple-nodemcu-web-server/)) (it is saved as a single string in the board code so apologies for formatting weirdness):

```
<style>  
.button{    
     background-color:red;    
     color:blue;    
     border-radius: 8px;    
     padding: 12px 24px;  
}
</style>
<h1>Simple NodeMCU Web Server</h1>
<p>    
  <a href=\"LEDOn\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a>    
  &nbsp;    
  <a href=\"LEDOff\"><button>OFF</button></a>
</p>
```

This works great.  Any time I click the button to load "LEDOn" the page [IP_ADDRESS]/LEDOn loads and the LED turns on.

Since I have a number of these little servers running I'd like to have a single page with buttons to control all of them.  The problem is that if I create an "on" button for a remote board:

```
<form action="http://[IP_ADDRESS]/LEDOn">

        <input type="submit" value="On" />
    </form>
```

The remote LED turns on (good) but I also navigate to the /LEDOn page and away from my master interface page (bad).  I'd like to do the former without the latter.

After reading around it looks like AJAX might be the answer but a modified bit of code from the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started):

```
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").addEventListener('click', makeRequest);

  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://IP_ADDRESS/LEDOn');
    httpRequest.send();
  }
  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
  })();
```

Doesn't appear to do much of anything.

Am I on the right track here?  If so, what am I missing? If not, is there a better way to think about this problem?  I'm looking for a lightweight way to achieve my primary goal, and am more than happy to be told that I'm going about trying to do so all wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are on the right lines - AJAX is the way to go. You can also achieve it via routing the request via a hidden iframe. Either way, the page is 'loaded' somewhere - it's just that the visitor doesn't see that load. Provide more details re: "does appear to do much of anything" and we can help. Check the browser's console for any errors and also the network tab to see if the AJAX request is fired.

Comment: Thanks!  Here's the error message from the console (didn't even occur to me to look there): "Failed to load http://[IP_ADDRESS]/LEDOn: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Right, that means you're falling foul of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (SOP), which says that you can't, by default, AJAX to domains other than the one on which your script is running and be able to access the response. The browser will block it. You can get round this, if you control the target domain, by having it output a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http//referrer.domain' header. If you can't, the hidden iframe way is the way to go.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much!  I'll dig into that now, somewhat more confident that I am at least digging in the right direction.

Comment: Good luck......